# Keras model feature output is all zeros during prediction of a single image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For a project I'm extracting the features of images but have run into a problem. After using transfer learning on efficientnet, I load the model, remove the last 2 layers (dropout and softmax) then use model.predict to get the feature array. This works fine when working in batches but with a single image it breaks. Here's my code for the single image:

```
model = load_model('best_model.h5')
model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=model.layers[-3].output)

model.summary()

#img_path = 'test_img_new/大葱/20113.jpg'
img_path = '1359.jpg'

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(260,260,3))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = preprocess_input_E(x)
x = np.array(x,dtype=np.float32)
#x = x/255
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)


res = model.predict(x,batch_size=1)

print(res.tolist())
```

and the output is just:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: please define `preprocess_input_E`??

Comment: What is the output when you don't specify `batch_size` parameter to the `model.predict()` function ?

Comment: @M.Innat preprocess is efficientnet’s preprocess function. It’s redundant now as Kerala has implemented it within the model.

Comment: @Kishore it’s an array close to all zeros, but non zero. Which isn’t right anyway. The weird thing is when I run the model through using a batch of 64 images, it works fine.

Comment: then why you're using it?

Comment: Maybe some custom model code has problems with `batch_size=1`, e.g. batch normalization not well defined for eval mode. Maybe try to set `batch_size=2` and put the same image twice - does it give correct results or those zeroes x2?

Comment: @M.Innat copied and pasted from old project, didn’t bother taking it out

Comment: @dankal444 just tried that, doesn't work. I've also noticed some problems, such as during prediction with batches, if the batch is shuffled (many different categories) performs much better than if the batch was not shuffled (one single category). I'm assuming this has something to do with the batchnorm at inference time, will update this post if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing stackoverflow and github for a ridiculous amount of time, I found the solution.

It turns out that batch normalization was not performing correctly during inference. As per the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/), the Batch Normalizaiton layer should use the moving average and standard deviation from training. However, this was now happening because during training I had manually set `trainable=True`. The solution was to load the model again, then specifcally set the layer to `trainable=False`

```
for layer in model.layers:
    if "BatchNormalization" in layer.__class__.__name__:
        layer.trainable=False
        print(layer.weights)
```

Then, save and use the model directly. It seems that compiling was not needed for this to take effect, and this may be a bug which should be investigated in the future.

**NOTE:** This seemed to work for tensorflow 2.3 but not 2.1. This may be due to the model being trained on tf 2.3, but I'm unsure of the reasoning.